# Display the 2nd longest word(s) in the text with comma separator(s) in C#

Tags: c#, word-count

I'm wondering how to display the 2nd longest words(list) in the text with comma separator(s)?

The following is the code for finding the 2nd longest words (no duplicates)

*The result should display a list of 2nd longest word(s)  apples, lemons (with comma separator) in Label* but it only shows single result Lemons at the moment. How can I display it both with comma separator(s)?

I'm new to programming so simpler coding would be great

Thank you all in advance~

```
string st = "I like apples. I like red apples. I like red apples, lemons and green bananas.";

            char[] sep = new char[] { '.', ',', ' ' };

            string secondLongestWord = (from words in st.Split(sep).Distinct().ToArray()
                                        orderby words.Length descending
                                        select words).Take(2).Last().ToString();


            var query = from words in st.Split(sep).Distinct().ToArray()
            where words.Length == secondLongestWord.Length
            select words;

            foreach (string word in query)
            {
                this.lbl2ndLongest.Text = word;             

            }
```

Comment: If you want words whose `Length` is the same as `secondLongestWord.Length`, that's what you should put in the `where` clause - right now you're trying to compare an integer to a string, which is what the compiler is telling you.

Comment: Oh, how silly was I! where words.Length == secondLongestWord.Length    Thanks Preston!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an answer to your error (as pointed out in the comments), but I wanted to suggest that you could group the words by length and select the second longest word(s) directly:

```
var secondLongestWords = (from word in st.Split(sep).Distinct()
                          group word by word.Length into g
                          select g).OrderByDescending(g => g.Key).ElementAtOrDefault(1);
```

To turn that into a comma separated list:

```
string list = null;
if (secondLongestWords != null)
{
    list = string.Join(", ", secondLongestWords);
}
```

Comment: Hi adrift, thanks but how to display more than one result with comma separator(s) between words? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! It worked great! but I have no idea of using ElementAtOrDefault(1)..... so I replaced my old coding to your new coding but that combination returns one value. Could I still use my old coding with your string list block? Thanks :)

Comment: `ElementAtOrDefault(1)` returns the 2nd element in the enumerable or `null` if there is no 2nd element.  If you want to take the 1st element if there is only 1 element, then yes, you can use what you have with `.Take(2).Last()`.

Comment: Oh, I get it! Thanks a lot adrift! :)

Answer (score -5):

The `String` class has a number of useful operations, including the `Length` property, which returns the total number of characters in a given string object. The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String(v=vs.110).aspx) has a full list.

Comment: The OP has already shown that they are aware of the `.Length` property. You didn't show any code to demonstrate how it might be useful to answering the question. Both of which are probably why you're getting downvotes (not from me, yet), in case you're wondering.